# WPF DataGrid Not Binding to Collection

Tags: wpf

For some reason my DataGrid which is contained in a WPF UserControl is not binding to a collection. It always comes out with headers only and none of the rows for the content are added.

**Users.xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class Users : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> _userViewModels;

        public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> UserViewModels
        {
            get { return _userViewModels; }
            set { _userViewModels = value;  }
        }

        public Users()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateUsers(); 
        }      

        private void PopulateUsers()
        {
            _userViewModels = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>() 
            {
                new UserViewModel() { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Doe"}, 
                new UserViewModel() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"}
            };

            this.DataContext = _userViewModels; 
        }


    }
```

**Users.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Users.Views.Users"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=UserViewModels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"></DataGridTextColumn>           
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</UserControl>
```

Can anyone notice anything I am missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

I updated the XAML code to the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=UserViewModels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Now, I can see the DataGrid but it does not have any values. It is all empty! Even though I am populating two fields "FirstName" and "LastName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Also, binding is more useful if you have `ViewModel`.

The reason why it didn't work the first time is because you were trying to set the **entire view** as the `DataContext`. Therefore, the binding was trying to look for a property of `UserViewModels` inside the `UserViewModels`.

Change

```
this.DataContext = _userViewModels;
```

to

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

and put the bindings back what it originally is

```
ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModels}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was simple. To the point and correct. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I can use {Binding} in ItemsSource to bind to individual record in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ItemsSource` binding to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

`DataContext`, for whole `UserControl`, is already set to your collection when you do

```
this.DataContext = _userViewModels
```

so all you need to do is bind `ItemsSource` to current `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your bindings and set the DataContext of the UserControl. This can be done strictly in xaml as shown below.

**xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Users.Views.Users"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>        
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

and remove this line:

```
this.DataContext = _userViewModels;
```

The above code will set the current DataContext of the UserControl to itself. When this is applied, you are able to bind accordingly, as shown above. Note that your XAML did not have anything binding to your Last Name column, so I added that as well.